# How to approximate a solution

Tags: equation-solving

Here comes a simple code

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Vn = (-G*Mn)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + cn^2];
Vd = (-G*Md)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (s + Sqrt[h^2])^2];
Vb = (G*Mb)/(2*a)*(ArcSinh[(x - a)*(y^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)] - 
 ArcSinh[(x + a)*(y^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)]);
Vh = (-G*Mh)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + ch^2];
Vrot = -(Ωb^2/2)*(x^2 + y^2);

Vt = Vn + Vd + Vb + Vh + Vrot;

G = 1; Mn = 400; cn = 0.25;
Md = 7000; s = 3; h = 0.175;
Mb = 3500; a = 3; c = 1;
Mh = 20000; ch = 20;
Ωb = 8.765;
```

Now let's find an equilibrium point

```
Vx = D[Vt, x];
Vy = D[Vt, y];
solL1 = FindRoot[{Vx == 0, Vy == 0}, {{x, 10}, {y, 0}}];
xL = Abs[x /. solL1[[1]]]
```

For the above values of the parameters we have that xL = 5.00092.

The particular value of `xL` strongly depends on the value of $\Omega_b$.

Now I want the following: find for which value of $\Omega_b$ `xL` would be equal to 10. Of course I could start changing by hand the value of $\Omega_b$ until I hit `xL = 10` but I want an automatic approach on this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can cast this as an optimization problem. The most general form would probably be to treat the algorithm that finds `xL` as a black box and use a gradient free optimizer (see [NMinimize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html)).

Comment: @Sascha I ma not quite sure of what you propose. Could you elaborate your approach to a detailed solution?

Answer (score 1):

Make Vrot, Vt, Vx and Vy to be functions of Ωb

```
Vrot[Ωb_] := -(Ωb^2/2)*(x^2 + y^2);
Vt[Ωb_] := Vn + Vd + Vb + Vh + Vrot[Ωb];
Vx[Ωb_] := D[Vt[Ωb], x];
Vy[Ωb_] := D[Vt[Ωb], y];
```

Now use NumericQ with FindRoot:

```
solL2[Ωb_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[{Vx[Ωb] == 0, Vy[Ωb] == 0}, {x, 10}, {y, 0}]
```

Use FindRoot again !

```
FindRoot[solL2[Ωb] == 10, {Ωb, 5}]

{Ωb -> 3.4677}
```